# update fields in ngRepeat based on another field in same index

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to populate a text input field inside an ng-repeat loop with the value of another field inside that same loops index when I click a button.

JSFiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/3FKMx/

When the `Copy Names` button is clicked I want each text box to be populated with the same value that's in the array. Currently it populates them all with the value of the last item in the array.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function someController($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["name1","name2","name3"];

    $scope.copyNames = function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.names,
        function (value){
          $scope.newName = value;
        }
      );
    };

}
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="copyNames()">Copy Names</button>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
          <td>{{name}}</td>

          // I want to populate this input with {{ name }} when I click the button above.
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="newName"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3FKMx/1/)

With an updated data structure it's a bit nicer for looping through.

[Solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3FKMx/3/)

Create a new array to store the values. Set them by key and look them up by key in your curly braces.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="copyNames()">Copy Names</button>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
          <td>{{name}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="models[name]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function someController($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["name1","name2","name3"];
    $scope.models = {};

    $scope.copyNames = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.names,
            function (value, key) {
                $scope.models[value] = value;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: The nameItems are coming from an AJAX request as an array, is there anyway to do it without having to loop through and convert it to an array of objects?

Comment: @greg - Yep, sure. If you have that restriction then try this and I'll update my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/3FKMx/3/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KbzCF/)</kbd> (updated your fiddle) is what you are looking for?

Tried using an object to hold the label and model:

```
$scope.names = [{label: "name1", model: ''},
                {label: "name2", model: ''},
                {label: "name3", model: ''}];


//Also using jQuery.each to break from the loop 
//once we know which value to copy
$scope.copyNames = function() {
   $.each($scope.names,
      function (i, value){
          if(value.model) {
            angular.forEach($scope.names, function(name){
                name.model = value.model;
            });

            //Break the loop if done copying
            return false;
         }
      }
   );
};
```

Note: jQuery is used as an external library which will be available in angular as is.